# Update widget with service when app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, widget

I have a widget in my application, but i must update its `TextView` from a `service` when app is closed

This is my widget:

```js
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);

            Log.i("onUpdate","onUpdate");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
        Log.i("onEnable","onEnable");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
        Log.i("onDisabled","ondisabled");
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                int appWidgetId) {
        
        
        CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

        Log.i("onUpdateAppWidget","onUpdateAppWidget");


        // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


}
```

I must update it every second

Comment: So do you want to update it every second, or when the app closes?

Comment: i want to update it every second and when the app closes too

Comment: @ManuelePerrone You can use Services (developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to achieve this.  And please be specific about where you have a problem. Don't go to "I want this (especially when "this" has multiple problems involved).

Comment: @VipulKumar what i must add to my service for update my widget?
And, how i run the service when i kill my app?

Comment: Your first question is not answerable unless you get the answer to the second question. Services are meant to be running in background, so they run even when app is closed. Please read the documentation about Services (the link I provided). You can also refer to the tutorial by Mr. Vogel www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial and documentation links I provided in comments are straightforward about implementing a simple Service in Android. 
Once you get to that, you can run a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in your service. 
IMHO, CounDownTimer is by far the best tool to do something every second, as you wish to implement it. It provides a simple method onTick which is called every second until you stop the timer.

```
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    updateWidget();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. In your service class sent the Data to widget class through  broadcast and In your widget class register broad cast receiver inside onUpdate and implement BroadcastReceiver class. Inside broadcast receiver class update your text, I mean put your remote view and manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews); . You are done !